# Как можно сверстать вот такую кнопку удаления (красный крестик)?

Tags: html, css3

(Крестик  справа от  надписи).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="add-title"> Купить лошадь </div>
<div class="add-description">По цене 300 т.р. за штуку</div>
```

Comment: Покажи верстку...

Comment: <div class="add-title">
 Купить лошадь
</div>
<div class="add-description">По цене 300 т.р. за штуку</div>

Comment: Ну и....??? Не возникло мысли в `<div class="add-title">` засунуть другой элемент с абсолютным позиционированием? Например `span` или тот же самый `div`?

Comment: Судя по вопросу, ожидается цикл вопросов, 

`1. Как сунуть в DIV крестик?` 

`2. Как нажать на  <div class="add-title"> Купить лошадь </div>, чтобы в <div class="add-description"> появилась цена`
 

`3. Как нажать на крестик, чтобы очистить  <div class="add-description">По цене 300 т.р. за штуку</div>`

Comment: Я просто новичок и туплю пока что ещё. С 1 и 2 вопросом вы правы). Нужно крестик через background-image добавить? Просто у меня не получается

Comment: Denis, не переживай, все когда-то начинали... Прости за сарказм, но ты сам перечитай свой вопрос ни как автор... Тебе  он понятен??? Покажи, что сделал, как делал, добавь `css` и тебе помогут... Под вопросом кнопка `править` нажми `редактирование примера` и далее разберешься...

Comment: вроде бы на русском языке сказали как сделать : https://otvet.mail.ru/question/213666452

Comment: http://fontawesome.ru/icon/times/   вообще вот это самый лучший вариант

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rRvrmK  - вот реализация

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен именно сам крестик, то можете воспользоваться [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.com/) - это шрифтовые иконки.

```css
.delete {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fas fa-times delete"></i>
```

---

Если не хотите подключать "целую библиотеку", то воспользуйтесь сайтом [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/) - иконки в различных форматах.

```css
.delete {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLnMQ.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="delete"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
.del {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.del::before,
.del::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1rem;
  height: .1rem;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin: -.05rem 0 0 -.4rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: .1rem;
}

.del::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="del"></span>
<span class="del"></span>
```